# Empty list variable stored as type 'None'

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, windows-7-x64

I am trying to write a short function in Python 3.3.2.  Here's my module:

```
from math import sqrt
phi = (1 + sqrt(5))/2
phinverse = (1-sqrt(5))/2

def fib(n): # Write Fibonacci numbers up to n using the generating function
    list = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        list = list.append(int(round((phi**i - phinverse**i)/sqrt(5), 0)))
    return(list)

def flib(n): # Gives only the nth Fibonacci number
    return(int(round((phi**n - phinverse**n)/sqrt(5), 0)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    fib(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

When I run fibo.fib(6), I get the following error:

```
    list = list.append(int(round((phi**i - phinverse**i)/sqrt(5), 0)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How do I rectify this error?

Comment: never use `list` for variable name. It is an inbuilt type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return type of

```
list.append
```

is `None`

When you do `list = list.append(int(round((phi**i - phinverse**i)/sqrt(5), 0)))`

it is assigning `list=None`

Just do

```
for i in range(0,n):
    list.append(int(round((phi**i - phinverse**i)/sqrt(5), 0)))
```

Also, `list` is an builtin type. So use a different variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The `append` call doesn't return a list, it will update in place.

```
list = list.append(int(round((phi**i - phinverse**i)/sqrt(5), 0)))
```

should become

```
list.append(int(round((phi**i - phinverse**i)/sqrt(5), 0)))
```

You should probably also call the argument something other than `list` because that word it used to identify the list class as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
def fib(n):
    '''Write Fibonacci numbers up to n using the generating function'''

    return [int(round((phi**i - phinverse**i)/sqrt(5), 0))) for i in range(0, n)]
```